# Bootstrap progress bar with ng-style AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I have problem with progress bar and ng-style 
Here's my code :

```
<div class="progress" >
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ng-style="width:datas[0].downloading">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download" ></span>
 </div>
 </div>
```

My plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/g1t4pludTTIAJYKTToCK?p=preview
Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: width:datas[0].downloading gives error.

Answer (score 1):

Close with  curly braces like: `ng-style="{width:datas[0].downloading}"`

<kbd>[Fixed demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/d2raQXV2ewnzw2kjrHY1?p=preview)</kbd>